# Device is not being detected in MobileFirst Operations Console

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed the application to my real device. In  MobileFirst operations console,under the devices tap my device is not being detected. it's like device(0)

Answer (score 0):

Priya, I did a test in my environment and see that a device is shown in the console when I run the app.  My belief is that your app does not connect to the server, and therefore the device does not show up.  For example, if you just created a simple HelloWorld app that does not have any additional code, the app will not connect to the server when it is run, and the server will not know about the device.  But if you add a call to WL.Client.Connect() in your wlCommonInit function in main.js, then the device should show up in the console.  If this does not help, please provide more details such as the version that you are using, the type of app, the requests that the app makes to the server, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tom, We are using ionic with mfp plugins. In there if we use WL.Client.Connect(), we are getting error as "It is not a Function". Can you help us regarding ,how to connect existing cordova application to the mfp console.
Configuration:
mfp server : 8.0.0 beta version
cordova : 6.1.1
node : 4.4.3
android : 5.1.1

Comment: Priya, there is no such API "WL.Client.connect" in v8.0. Please stop whatever you are doing and start learning v8.0; do not use v7.x APIs with v8.0.